# Why were humans better hosts than Unas to the Goa'uld?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

When they are introduced, the Unas appear to be stronger physically than humans but otherwise have similar capacities - they have gripping hands, for instance, and can clearly make tools.  Since the body is just the vehicle for the parasite, why would the Goa'uld not stick with the Unas? What was it about humans that made them the clear choice for all Goa'uld after they were discovered?

Comment: The Unas have pretty good healing capacities even without parasites, that would seem to make them attractive hosts (obviously not in the aesthetic sense).

Comment: Can Goa'uld parasites even take them over or does Una healing abilities fight them off, as in their immune system defeats the parasites? Or maybe I missed something?

Comment: @jo1storm indeed they could. That was the reason behind their name in the series, where "Unas" was understood to be something like "first ones" or "first hosts".   The idea was that they evolved on the same planet as the parasites

Comment: Unas are stronger and more resilient, but it probably comes at a cost of requiring more energy to feed and repair. They potentially are less numerous than humans, who are already scattered everywhere, so as a potential labor force and pool for hosts, humans offer a lot better options.

Also, Goa'uld scavenged technology from the Ancients, which means humans are a lot more optimized for using that tech.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know, actually, the human population was "scattered everywhere" because the Goa'uld put them there. Presumably, they could have just as easily done the same with Unas.

Comment: Note that they didn't often take the beefiest humans as hosts -- they often chose slender, delicate and strangely beautiful.

Comment: @computercarguy Oh yeah! I can't believe I forgot about that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [Stargate Wiki](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Unas):

> "humans proved to be a much more suitable host-race for the Goa'uld,
> as human bodies were easier to repair, and human hands and voices
> offered much greater expressive and tool-using abilities; the Unas as
> hosts were phased out."

It seems like this is explained in the episode [Thor's Hammer](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Thor%27s_Hammer_(episode)).

Comment: Also, humans have far more variety in appearance - something which appealed to the vanity of the Goa'uld.

Comment: @Omegacron Is that true? Or is that a matter of our human eyes being better at picking out differences between individual humans than between individual Unas?

Comment: I wonder if "easier to repair" refers to the Ancient healing technology that was created for a species related to humans, i.e. not compatible with Unas. Anyone have any examples of healing technology or its Goa'uld derivative working on non-humans?

Comment: @WillihamTotland Funnily enough, there's recently been a study that finally actually tested the phenomenon where people think all blacks/asians/whatever look the same - and they found that nope, it's not racism. Humans of European descent are much easier to distinguish from each other, even to non-Europeans. Among other animals, the ability to distinguish individuals is incredibly rare - it only evolves in an environment where that kind of thing is useful, and that mostly centres around animals doing favours to each other (and cheating, of course).

Comment: @WillihamTotland The Unas are distinguishable, but nowhere near to the extent the humans of Stargate are, visually. And it seems that either the Goa'uld prefer slender hosts by some quirk of their evolution, or they take after their host in this as well - we know from the Tok'ra that a lot of the host actually does affect the parasite. Even if that wasn't the case, the Goa'uld love power, and would certainly choose the hosts that are the most conducive to that - in violent societies, they'd presumably choose big, imposing hosts (like the Asgard holograms); in more orderly, beautiful.

Comment: @Luaan I don't know what your metric for "incredibly" rare is, but being able to distinguish individuals is useful in any social species.

Comment: @WillihamTotland - that's difficult to say, because we're all human. Within the show, though, humans had a hard time telling various Unas apart. The exception to this was Daniel Jackson, who could apparently identify individual Unas on sight. My comment, though, was regarding the external appearance of Unas vs. humans. Humans have a wide variety of skin, eye & hair color... and that's something that would appeal to the vain Goa'uld who placed importance on appearance.

Answer (score 1):

They chose humans because they ruled by impersonating gods of human cultures. The Unas are a primative species and could not be used as slaves or support civilizations; whereas the humans could function as an entire economy even if at a non-technological level.

Humans would most likely have rebeled against an Unas as God figure. Moreover, the Jafa were modified humans as well. Though we don't know if the Unas could have been suitably modified as well.